# "flutter build apk" for release in Flutter get error

Tags: flutter, build, apk, release

I want to build apk release on Flutter, I already follow and implemented this link: https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android for pro-guards, key, etc.

But when I run "`flutter build apk`". I get the error.

https://pastebin.com/mEjkvQxP

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to migrate your project to AndroidX. Check this guideline to migrate to AndroidX.
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility#how-to-migrate-a-flutter-app-to-androidx